# How to check file with multiple extension using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, file

I want to check if some file exists with multiple extension. I tried this way, it works. But I need the simple way to do this process. Is anyone can give me advice how to improve this process? Thank you so much.

```
$Data = "D:\Folder"

if (!(Test-Path $Data\*.que))
{
     if (!(Test-Path $Data\*.pro))
     {
          if (!(Test-Path $Data\*.err))
          {
               if (!(Test-Path $Data\*.skip))
               {
                    Write-Host "Complete"
               }
               else {

                    Write-Host "Finished, But Not Complete"
               }
          }
          else {

               Write-Host "Finished, But Not Complete"
          }
     }
     else {

          Write-Host ".pro Exist, Not Finished"
     }
}
else {

     Write-Host ".que Exist, Not Finished"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have some custom messages depending on filetype, you could approach this in a few ways. One way would be to put all into a CSV and iterate over that. To simplify the code it seems logical to check if the file exists rather than not. It could look something like this.

```
$CSVData = @'
Extension,NotPresent,Present
que,".que Exist, Not Finished",
pro,".pro Exist, Not Finished",
err,"Finished, But Not Complete",
skip,"Complete","Finished, But Not Complete"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Data = "D:\Folder"

$CSVData | foreach {
    if(Test-Path "$Data\*.$($_.extension)")
    {
        Write-Host $_.present
    }
    else
    {
        write-host $_.notpresent
    }
}
```

I left the Present column empty except the one which you actually responded to. If you don't need to fill those in, you may want to check if there is anything in `$_.present` before `Write-Host`

```
$CSVData = @'
Extension,NotPresent,Present
que,".que Exist, Not Finished",
pro,".pro Exist, Not Finished",
err,"Finished, But Not Complete",
skip,"Complete","Finished, But Not Complete"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$Data = "D:\Folder"

$CSVData | foreach {
    if(Test-Path "$Data\*.$($_.extension)")
    {
        if($null -ne $_.present)
        {
            Write-Host $_.present
        }
    }
    else
    {
        write-host $_.notpresent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Folder' -File -Recurse).Extension | Group-Object
```

You can `Get-ChildItem` to get files in a directory and only grab the extension property of the returned object, then `Group-Object` to get a list of directories and how many of each exist